# devenv and vsewss 1.3 package

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sharepoint, vsewss

I'm tying to package a vsewss 1.3 solution in cmd. I get it to build and all seems to work until it starts the deployment then i get the error message: Specified method is not supported.

my command is:
devenv xxx.sln /deploy Release /package
has also tried:
devenv xxx.sln /deploy Release

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the solution in visual studio and seeing the package inside the WSP View (View => Other Windows), see if there's any problem with the solution parsing.

Also, any specific reason to create the package outside Visual Studio?

Comment: I can see all the wsp's there. And it workes fine in Visual Studio.